# Proving a non-prime (composite) number $> 1$ has a divisor $d \leq\sqrt q$

Tags: logic

I'm looking prove using an indirect proof that:

If an integer $q < 1$ is composite, then $q$ will have some divisor $d$ such that $d >
\sqrt{q}$.

I really just don't know how to even start this thing, most examples i've seen or done have been much more trivial than this.  My best guess is that I must assume $q > 1$ is prime and that it has a divisor d such that $d > \sqrt q$?  What then can I say about this statement that would prove, im assuming by contraposition that the about statement is true?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, I know it's a lot to ask.

Comment: Why did you completely change around the question by changing $>$ to $<$ and $\leq$ to $>$?

Answer (score 0):

If $d\mid n$ and $d\leq \sqrt{n}$ then we are done. If $d>\sqrt{n}$ then $\frac nd\mid n$ and $\frac nd <\sqrt{n}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_0,a_2,...,a_m$ the divisors of $n$ ($a_0=1,a_m=n$).
We have $a_k.a_{m-k}=n$ for all $n$.
Now, because $n$ is not prime, exist $a_1\neq n$, if $a_1\geq \sqrt{n}$, we have $n=a_1.a_{m-1}\geq a_1.a_1\geq n$ and all signs are equals $\to a_1=a_{m-1}$.

Now, the divisors of n are three and $n$ are perfect square number, and has the divisor $\sqrt{n}$.

Answer (score 0):

Say $q$ is composite and has divisors only $\ge \sqrt{n}$. Let one of the divisors be $d$. Then $d$ . $x = n$ where $d \ge \sqrt{n}$. Since $\sqrt{n}$ x $\sqrt{n} = n$, $x \le \sqrt{n}$.